# Using regular expressions in the `html_nodes` function of the rvest package

Tags: r, regex, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to create a function that uses the `html_nodes` function from the `rvest` package. My function takes in a URL of the main page of any Medium (the blogging/publishing platform) blog. It will generate links to each of the individual posts/articles on that particular Medium blog and save it in a list.

However, the design for each Medium blog differs. Hence, the css generated by SelectorGadget would also differ. Is there any way I can use regular expressions, particularly the pipe ("|") symbol to capture different ORs, such that my function can intelligently capture the links to each of the individual posts/articles on any given Medium blog.

My function is as follows:

```
get_url_suffix <- function(url) {
  url_suffix <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(".u-borderLighter|.gc .bv") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>%
    as.data.frame()
  
  return(url_suffix)
}
```

`.u-borderLighter` and `.gc .bv` are two examples which I have come across in the Medium blogs whose links I am intending to scrape (the scraping is successful when they are used individually).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should be able to use the CSS selector like this:

```
html_elements(".u-borderLighter, .gc .bv")
```

(Note that `html_nodes()` is deprecated and replaced by `html_elements()`.)